# Problems with the x and y axis

Tags: d3.js

I have some code that produces a scatterplot and uses differentiating colours to illustrate the football team in which they represent. Great. However, i'm having issues with the x and y axis. Whilst i am happy with the working code, the aesthetics of both axis' can aren't aligned and 'leaking' out of the svg. Therefore i'm looking for some assistance on how to make the x and y axis neater and more central within the svg.

(It should be noted that the data it's using are cosine similarities)

Cheers

```js
var data = [
  [0.1457],
  [0.22436],
  [0.54356],
  [0.6634],
  [0.893456]
];

const colours = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(data)
  .range(["#A8A7A7", "#2F9599", "#E8175D", "#474747", "#CC527A"]);

var w = 800;
var h = 400;
var xPadding = 5;
var yPadding = 30;

var xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, w])
  .domain([0, 1]);

var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([h, 0])
  .domain([0, 1]);

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append("svg")
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(xscale)
  .ticks(0);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yscale)
  .ticks(0);

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xscale(d[0]);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yscale(d[0]);
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    var result = null;

    if (data.indexOf(d) >= 0) {
      result = colours(d);
    } else {

      result = "white";
    }
    return result;
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(25," + (h - xPadding) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + yPadding + ",15)")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

[image: My Scatterplot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first necessary change is setting the range for both scales using the paddings. Here I'm assuming that `xPadding` refers to the padding in the x axis, and `yPadding` refers to the padding in the y axis. Besides those, let's create a `padding` for the end of both axes.

That being said, these should be the scales:

```
var xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([xPadding, w - padding])
    .domain([0, 1]);

var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([h - yPadding, padding])
    .domain([0, 1]);
```

After that, you have to position the axes' groups. Do not use magic numbers, just use the same paddings in the scales:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - yPadding) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + xPadding + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Here is the demo with those changes, using 5 ticks:

```js
var data = [
  [0.1457],
  [0.22436],
  [0.54356],
  [0.6634],
  [0.893456]
];

const colours = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(data)
  .range(["#A8A7A7", "#2F9599", "#E8175D", "#474747", "#CC527A"]);

var w = 800;
var h = 400;
var xPadding = 30;
var yPadding = 20;
var padding = 10;

var xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([xPadding, w - padding])
  .domain([0, 1]);

var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([h - yPadding, padding])
  .domain([0, 1]);

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append("svg")
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(xscale)
  .ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yscale)
  .ticks(5);

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xscale(d[0]);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yscale(d[0]);
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    var result = null;

    if (data.indexOf(d) >= 0) {
      result = colours(d);
    } else {

      result = "white";
    }
    return result;
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - yPadding) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + xPadding + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that... I just have one question, when calling xAxis and yAxis, why use the yPadding variable for the xAxis and xPadding variable for the yAxis?

Comment: Because `yPadding` defines the padding in the y axis, and `xPadding` defines the padding in the x axis. All axes in D3 are created at the origin, and then you have to move them. You move the x axis vertically, on the y orientation, and the y axis horizontally, in the x orientation.